# Can moderators choose to mark an answer as accepted?

Tags: support

Does the SE/music.SE setup allow moderators (or anyone else other than a question author) to accept an answer on the author's behalf? Some people just aren't good at remembering to accept answers and where there is a clear best answer, marking it accepted seems like it's good to the site.

Comment: I think, and certainly hope, that this is not the case! That would go against the basic idea as I understand it. Only the asker can determine if he/she was helped by an answer. Others can benefit from the community's knowledge by having an answer that was not accepted being more upvoted.

Comment: People not accepting answers on their questions goes against the basic idea too. I agree it would have to be used very sparingly but when we look at bounties, we see the system decides who to award it to if the author can't be bothered so there's _some_ precedent.

Comment: Sounds like badness to me anyhow. It also sounds like this has been up for discussion, have you checked http://meta.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is in [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), namely in:

[Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18315/189976)

> **No**, this is a user-oriented site.
>
> It is intended to answer people's questions. They know their problem the best and know what solves it for them. We need to leave it up to them to accept whatever answer they want.  People will know what the community agrees with by the upvotes. The power to accept an answer should stay in the user/asker's hand. That way you have both opinions/views in a question.

StackExchange does not do exceptions in these rules for particular sites.

*(I'm not sure what is the policy if a Q on a child meta is a dupe of a Q on the big meta, I hope I didn't do anything wrong.)*

Comment: It's somewhat ironic that that question doesn't have an accepted answer...

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername I don't see anything ironic in that. I see something ironic in people cursing everybody who doesn't give them the rep points.

Comment: @yo' But there's nothing ironic about that.